# Fairness of assigning different reviewers for final decision on paper

Tags: peer-review, journals, journal-workflow

I recently submitted a paper to a journal. My paper came back with a reject and resubmission allowed decision. When I resubmitted the paper it went to other reviewers.

Under the journal's rules, this is the last time i will get reviews and after that paper will be either rejected or accepted. How is it fair to send the paper to different reviewers, who will than again give their comments on the paper? If the reviewers are changed shouldn't the author be given one more chance to address the comments?

Comment: We do not know the journal's rules, but generally the editor can do that and it is considered fair.

Comment: If two different sets of reviewers reject the paper, and you were given feedback adn chance to improve the paper after the first reject, it doesn't look unreasonable to me.

Comment: @NickS but after the first reject and chance to improve the paper , I am not allowed to improve it if gets rejected the second time.

Comment: I understand this, but publishing is not a game where a paper gets rejected and improved many times until it can get in. Also many journals don't give a second chance, so I don't see any issue with them giving a second chance but making it clear you won't get a third.... If the reviewrs don't have major concers or issues with the paper, they can always accept pending review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you submit a paper to a journal, you agree, in essence, to go by their rules and procedures for that paper until and unless it is rejected. It is too late, now, to object.

The fact that the editor wanted additional views of the paper is a good thing, for the journal and its readers. Their goal is to publish high quality papers.

And, if you are rejected, by whatever process, you have the opportunity to submit the paper elsewhere, of course.